# Hiding a div in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've just started using jQuery and I'm having some issues with it. I was trying something simple to get started, which is hiding a EMPLOYEES when a submit button is clicked. My jQuery code is:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("submit").click(function(){
            $(#title).toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

The html for the button is

```
    <input type="submit" value="SEARCH" name="submit" class="srchbutton">
```

When I click the button, nothing happens. I've tried a few different variations, and even tried writing it so that clicking the div itself hides it, but no luck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

It seems you don't use selectors correctly.

If you have a div with `id="title"` so use this:

```
$("input[type=submit]").click(function(){
    $("#title").toggle();
});
```

**Check this JSFiddle to see in action:
http://jsfiddle.net/9up7e8ka/**

Answer (score 0):

Is the button of type submit or did you forget the id tag #?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submit").click(function(){
            $("#title").toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

or

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("input[type=submit]").click(function(){
                $("#title").toggle();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using fadeToggle() than toggle(). It has a nice animation effect. 
Also, there should be a closing tag for external script files.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".srchbutton").click(function(){
             $("#title").fadeToggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```